# no funciona la etiqueta de descarga de html5

Tags: html5, css3

al aplicar la etiqueta de link y poner la ruta de la imagen que quiero que se descargue y al darle click no descarga la imagen, solo me la muestra en el navegador. ayuda
asi puse la etiqueta

```
<a href="dead.jpg" download="deadpool.jpg">Descarga la imagen de deadpool</a>
```

Comment: No agregues el código como imagen. debe quedar como texto

Comment: lo siento es que no se como hacer eso soy nuevo aqui

Comment: ya estaba como texto, solo déjala como estaba

Comment: ya esta como antes, te recomiendo así dejarla

Comment: ok muchas gracias amigo}

Answer (score 2):

para utilizar la etiqueta debes implementar la ruta exacta donde está el archivo, si es un documento como word, excel o hasta PDF no es necesario implementarla, es importante que la foto esté en el mismo directorio del proyecto, pero para una imagen te recomendaría lo siguiente:

```
<a href="http://localhost/miweb/images/hola.jpg" download>
  Descargar imagen
</a>
```

**Nota:** Para que el atributo download funcione, se debe realizar desde localhost o en el servidor del proyecto, es importante especificar la ruta absoluta donde esté la foto.

**Explicación:**

download HTML5

Este atributo, indica descargar a los navegadores una URL en lugar de navegar hacia ella, por lo que el usuario será dirigido para salvarla como un archivo local.  Si el atributo tiene un valor, éste se utilizará como nombre de archivo por defecto en el mensaje Guardar que se abre cuando el usuario hace clic en el enlace (sin embargo, el usuario puede cambiar el nombre antes de guardar el archivo). No hay restricciones sobre los valores permitidos, aunque: / y: \ se convertirán en guiones bajos (underscores), lo que evitará sugerencias de ruta específicas.  Se debe tener en cuenta que la mayoría de los sistemas de archivos tienen limitaciones con respecto a los símbolos de puntuación admitidos en los nombres de archivo, por lo que los navegadores ajustarán los nombres de los archivos en consecuencia.

Notas:

- Este atributo sólo funciona para las políticas de mismo origen
  (same-origin URLs).
- Este atributo puede ser utilizado con blob: URLs y data: URLs para
  descargar contenido generado por JavaScript, tales como fotografías
  creadas por una aplicación web de edición de imágenes.
- Si el encabezado (header) HTTP Content-Disposition: proporciona un
  nombre de archivo diferente al de este atributo, el encabezado HTTP
  tiene prioridad sobre este atributo.
- Si Content-Disposition: está ajustado a inline, Firefox prioriza
  Content-Disposition, como en el caso del nombre de archivo, mientras
  que Chrome prioriza el atributo download.

Fuente: [Elemento a](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a)

Comment: Pero no la descarga, solo la carga en el navegador

Comment: bueno la imagen esta dentro de la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo html5...pero intentare la forma que me dices

Comment: Efectivamente, al tratarse de un sitio web diferente lo abre como un recurso y no como un archivo, pero haz lo mismo con la ruta desde donde se encuentra la foto en tu localhost, yo lo acabo de hacer y funciona.

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo de como lo hiciste lo ultimo que me dices por favor

Comment: Ya actualicé mi respuesta, básicamente lo único que necesitas es especificar la ruta de tu directorio donde guardas la imagen, ejemplo: `<a href="miproyectoweb/images/foto.jpg" download>Descargar</a>` o si lo haces en localhost incluyes la url del proyecto.

Comment: me parece solo le va a funcionar corriendo desde localhost, indicando la ruta absoluta de la imagen, en caso contrario solo abre la imagen dentro de la ventana del navegador

Comment: sabes lo intente de las 2 formas que me dicen y me da el mismo resultado no descarga nada solo muestra la imagen en el navegador...no se si sera por el navegador es la ultima version de chrome

Comment: ¿@Kenny lo ejecutaste desde `localhost`, escribiendo en el `href` la ruta absoluta desde `http:localhost....` ?, por que yo lo acabo de hacer así y funciona

Comment: @Aprendiz sí, tienes razón, solo va funcionar desde localhost, probé lo mismo desde un html externo y no lo descarga, solo la muestra en el navegador como dice Kenny

Answer (score 2):

Prueba el siguiente codigo que te permite bajar la imagen desde el navegador, ya lo probe y funciona en chrome, firefox y edge...

```html
    <a download="custom-filename.png" href="img01.png" title="ImageName">
        <img alt="ImageName" src="img01.png">
    </a>
```

Donde:
los atributos donwload="" es el nombre que se le dara al archivo para bajar, debe ser la misma extension. href="" es el nombre del archivo con su ruta. src="" es nombre de la imagen con su ruta. alt="" nombre alternativo si no consigue la imagen.  title="" nombre que muestra al apuntar a la imagen.

Si lo que deseas es bajar imagenes debes colocar la etiqueta IMG dentro de la etiqueta anchor < a > < / a >

Comment: como asi poner la etiqueta dentro de la etiqueta anchor

Comment: no es necesario colocar la etiqueta img

Comment: la imagen se mostrara con la etiqueta img y el atributo src="" vas a colocar la ruta e le nombre de la imgen. ahora en la anchor / vinculo el parametro download="" es el nombre como se bajara el archivo

Comment: tienes razon, tambien funciona, se descargara con el texto contenido en el link